# Aws amplify signin, signup and confirm signing workflow issue

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have implemented AWS-Amplify in angular project and its working fine when it comes to sign up, sing in and confirm the user after signing up, but I am facing an issue with the flow and I am trying to find a walk around for it, my problem is when the user sign-up he will get redirected to the confirmation page to enter the confirmation code, after submitting the code the user have to sign in to access my website, so Im trying to sign in the user directly after successful signing up and confirming the account, but could not solve it, here is my code for signing up:

```
onSubmitSignup(value: any) {
    const email = value.email, password = value.password;
    let attributes: {
        username,
        phone_number,
    };
    this.auth.signUp(email, password, attributes)
        .subscribe(
            result => {
                this.successfullySignup = true;
                this.router.navigate(['/pages/confirmRegistration', result.user.username]);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.errorMessage = error.message;
            });
}
```

and in my auth service:

```
public signUp(email, password, userAttributes): Observable<any> {
    return fromPromise(Auth.signUp(email, password, userAttributes));
}
```

And here is the code to confirm the user:

```
onSubmitConfirmation(value: any) {
    const email = this.email, confirmationCode = value.confirmationCode;
    this.auth.confirmSignUp(email, confirmationCode)
        .subscribe(
            result => {
                this.auth.signIn(this.email, this.password); //this what im trying to achieve is to have the user data from the sign in and sign up components here in the confirmation component 
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.errorMessage = error.message;
            });
}
```

and the service for that:

```
public confirmSignUp(email, code): Observable<any> {
    return fromPromise(Auth.confirmSignUp(email, code));
}
```

my signing in method:

```
onSubmitLogin(value: any) {
  const email = value.email, password = value.password;
  this.auth.signIn(email, password)
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      },
      error => {
        this.errorMessage = error.message;
        if (error.code === 'UserNotConfirmedException') {
          this.router.navigate(['/pages/confirmRegistration']);
        }
      });
}
```

and the service for that:

```
public signIn(email, password): Observable<any> {
    return fromPromise(Auth.signIn(email, password))
        .pipe(
            tap(() => this.loggedIn.next(true))
        );
}
```

I though about having the username and password as a shared data between all my authentication components and then use them but thought that is not a good practice and did not manage to implement it, so if you can suggest a better approach to do that can you suggest it? I though about passing the email and password using:

```
this.router.navigate(['/pages/confirmRegistration', result.user.username]);
```

but this will expose the password in the url which I don't think its a good idea, I'm no expert but if it is please advice.

I even thought about having the confirmation method in the same components of each signIn and signUp but that will be duplicating the code but I might able to access the required fields for signing in after confirming the user.

Comment: I'm confused. What issue are you facing? Are you running into an error?

Comment: @ninadGaikwad no there is no errors, I just want to simplify the workflow for my users, my current work flow is sign-up --> confirm account --> sign-in --> access secured pages, what I want is sign-up --> confirm account --> access secured pages. is that clear now?